# Remove decimal number in dataframe column that is stored as object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have an issue where the data is stored under a dataframe like an object, which I don't mind at all, however some of the rows that are integers have a trailing .0 and I haven't been able to truncate them.

| ID | column_object |
| --- | --- |
| adssfdg | D1esdf |
| jAEOJDS | NaN |
| SDFJKFAS | NaN |
| DSFADSF | 323653.0 |
| SDFASF | 43253.0 |

I would like to remove that trailing 0 in order for the final data to look something like this:

| ID | column_object |
| --- | --- |
| adssfdg | D1esdf |
| jAEOJDS | NaN |
| SDFJKFAS | NaN |
| DSFADSF | 323653 |
| SDFASF | 43253 |

Any tips on how to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind converting the integers to strings, then you could use `str.rstrip`:

```
df['column_object'] = df['column_object'].where(lambda x: x.isna(), df['column_object'].astype(str).str.rstrip('.0'))
```

But if you want to keep the integers as integers, you could use `numpy.where`. But this will be really weird down the road when you process this data:

```
import numpy as np
tmp = pd.to_numeric(df['column_object'], errors='coerce')
df['column_object'] = np.where(tmp.notna(), tmp.fillna(0).astype(int), df['column_object'])
```

Output:

```
         ID column_object
0   adssfdg        D1esdf
1   jAEOJDS           NaN
2  SDFJKFAS           NaN
3   DSFADSF        323653
4    SDFASF         43253
```

Comment: as soon as I did that all the numerical values where set to NaN

Comment: yep that does the trick I also try this one and it seems to the same: df['column_object'] = df['column_object'].astype(str).replace(r'\.0$', '', regex=True), I went over and convert them as string as there's a merge that needs to happen with a table that was downloaded from mssql and the values are on string. Thanks man you were super helpful.